# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on graphical start with Linux 4.15.0-44

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel

I have a very strange issue here. I updated my machine's kernel to `4.15.0-44`. After a restart the whole machine was messed up. Some more digging around I managed to disable my graphical X server permanently in systemd.

After this, I was able to start my machine both with `4.15.0-43` and `4.15.0-44`. In the `-43` version I can still start the graphical interface manually and after reenabling it, can use it again.

The `-44` version is of another type. The machine starts regularly up to the point, where the graphical interface would appear (rough guess). The monitor gets black (normal) to change the screen resolution.
Unfortunately, the monitor never comes back to life. Nothing useful is displayed anymore and my input devices are non-functional. I cannot change to any tty not change the state of the Num-Lock-LED on the keyboard.

Using MagicSysRq I can at least reobtain control over my Num-Lock-LED, but this is all. I have to restart the machine in a hard manner.

Reinstalling the Linux packages seems to have not solved any problem.

For nor I use the `-43` version of Linux, but I am curious if this will be solved soon or what I can to to track this down further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See log at bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813745

I installed the 4.15.0-45 test kernel provided by Kai-Heng.

This fixes the issue, I can safely boot and login.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue as described in the bug reports. Seems like Linux Kernel 4.15.0-44 is causing it in some way. Here is my fix to just ban this version from my system (the 4.15.0-43 will be used at the time of writing):

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-*-4.15.0-44-generic
sudo apt remove linux-*-4.15.0-44-generic
```

Then reboot.

If you can't boot at all to get to the terminal in the first place, go to the grub boot menu (pressing ESC just after bios boot/reboot in my case) and choose any Linux Kernel version other than 4.15.0-44.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of graphic driver are you using? I had a similar problem with amd propietary drivers, deleted the corresponding `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` file and get X11 running again. After that, I had to reinstall amd graphic drivers

Comment: Hello, I have 2 graphic card installed: One of them uses i915 driver (`VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller` according to lspci) and one uses the `nvidia` driver (`VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M]`)

Comment: Then I'll guess is the same problem as me. Can you see what happens if you disable nvidia driver? (removing it or deleting the corresponding xorg file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`) and rebooting?.
If after that you get graphical interface, you can try to reinstall nvidia drivers or use alternate drivers